# Android OutOfMemoryError while uploading files

Tags: android, out-of-memory

i am using the code in this blog to upload files [tutorial Link](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/).
it's working fine but i am facing OutOfMemoryError if the file size is big.
i tried to use this method but it didn't work ( the request itself falls)

```
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
```

Also i tried to set the length of the header but it didn't work

```
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(((int) file.length()));
```

but this is also didn't work.
what i have to do??

Comment: Are you running this on the emulator or a real device?

Comment: both and it's the same in both

Comment: Try to set `maxBufferSize` to `4 * 1024`. May be 1MB too much for buffer. I actually doubt it won't hurt :)

Comment: Also you can try to flush outpustream on every iteration of while loop. May be outputstream buffers whole file until you call flush.

Comment: can you explain your last comment more.

Comment: [Flushing a Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)